# body have two different PhysicsSprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am doing a box2d application. I created 2 different body in the world. check this code

```
-(void)init{

 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sheet.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *parent = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sheet.png" capacity:100];
    spriteTexture_ = [parent texture];
    [self addChild:parent z:0 tag:kTagParentNode];
}
-(void)bodyCreation
{
 CCNode *parent = [self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode];

 PhysicsSprite *sprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bodySprite1.png"];
[parent addChild:sprite];

 b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
 ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
 ballBodyDef.bullet = true;
 ballBodyDef.position.Set(1210.0f/PTM_RATIO, 250.0f/PTM_RATIO);
 randombody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

 b2CircleShape circle;
 circle.m_radius = 16.0/PTM_RATIO;

 weightBallDef.shape = &circle;
 weightBallDef.density = 10.0f;
 weightBallDef.restitution = 0.2f;
 randomFixture = randombody->CreateFixture(&weightBallDef);
 [sprite setPhysicsBody:randombody];
}
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  CCNode *parent = [self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode];

  PhysicsSprite *sprite11 = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bodySprite2.jpg"];
  [parent addChild:sprite11];
  sprite11.position = ccp(touchBegin.x, touchBegin.y);

   b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
   ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
   ballBodyDef.bullet = true;
   ballBodyDef.position.Set(touchBeginLocationWorld.x, touchBeginLocationWorld.y);
   ballbody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

   b2PolygonShape box;
   box.SetAsBox(sprite11.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, sprite11.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);
   batShapeDef.shape = &box;
   batShapeDef.density = 10.0f;
   ballFixture = ballbody->CreateFixture(&batShapeDef);
   [sprite11 setPhysicsBody:ballbody];
}
```

My excepted result is like this:[image]

But some time i am getting like this:[image]

How to slove this. Any one help me...

Thanks...

Comment: have you tried creating just one body and seeing if it is allright ?

Comment: one body working fine, When tap the screen ccTouchesBegan body created after sometime i am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your touch to OpenGL (screen) coordinates before processing, like so:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
      location = [CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
```

Then set your sprite's position:

```
sprite11.position = location;
```

and your ball body definition:

```
ballBodyDef.position.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
```